# Efficient matrix multiplication in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices, `A` (N by K) and `B` (N by M) and I would like to concentrate `A` and `B` into a tensor `C` (N by K by M) where `C(n,k,m) = A(n,k) * B(n,m)`. I know how to do it in python like

```
C = B[:,numpy.newaxis,:] * A[:,:,numpy.newaxis]
```

Can anyone please tell me the matlab code that does the same thing efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the implicit expansion feature of [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). Use [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to have your `B` as an Nx1xM matrix:

```
C = bsxfun(@times, A, permute(B, [1, 3, 2]));
```

And from MATLAB **R2016b** onward, you can get the same result in this way:

```
C = A * permute(B, [1, 3, 2]);
```

Comment: I'd also mention the new MATLAB syntax ( for **R2016b** onward) that doesn't require `bsxfun`: (`C = A * permute(B, [1, 3, 2]);`).

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks, I included your suggestion.